# how to add aliases after boot programmatically

Tags: linux, archlinux, aliases

i am creating a program to load alias sets for example i need to do some dev work i want a load of helpfull aliases but mayby in my day to day operations i dont want to have these aliases and mayby some overlap ie dev work has rm='rm -i -r' and day to day has rm='rm -r' or doesnt want an alias at all and so on i have looked at a few sorces and all say to use .bash_aliases ro .bashrc and so on but thay cant be edited by command to sum it up i want to create a command ie 'loadaliases ' and then thoses aliases be loaded and all others be removed.

im using a arch-linux system with no gui just pure console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the aliases in a file, and then when you want to enable those aliases do:

```
source name_of_that_file
```

Comment: yes i have tryed that rn im testing it with loading two files aliases.sh and exports.sh i run them from an sh file in the same directory main.sh that contains

'source aliases.sh' and 'source exports.sh' but none of the aliases stick nor exports

Comment: Did you do `source main.sh`?

Comment: That's why the answer says `source` not `execute`. All scripts are run in a subshell. A subshell can never effect the environment of its parent. So you want to `source` not `execute`.

Comment: just one problem then how do i prevent a C program from beeing booted in a subshell?

Comment: Only shell scripts are being executed in a sub-shell (by default). Other applications are executed in current (again, by default) shell session with it's environment (read: aliases that I want) and shell is blocked until program terminates (or program spawns a process and leaves the shell available to you). All these are Linux (modern shell, in fact) fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash file that will get a parameter.
This parameter will separate the aliases you want to use and just run this bash.